# How to choose the right inductor for buck converter with LM5143A-Q1? (from TI)

Tags: voltage-regulator, inductor, buck, surface-mount, switching-regulator

While working on my first voltage regulator circuit I **got stuck at calculating the inductor value**... The IC is LM5143A-Q1 from Texas Instruments, and [**according to the datasheet**](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5143a-q1.pdf?ts=1690023068948&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM5143A-Q1), the formulas for calculating the required inductance are these:
[image]

I'm not sure **what I_L(peak), I_OUT, and ∆I_L mean**, nor how we can find them... I assume I_OUT is the maximum output current that it will need to provide, but don't know what the other two are. **How can we find the 3 variables mentioned above? Are there any formulas?**

At mouser, most inductors only include values like *max DC current/resistance and saturation current* (other than their actual inductance). If it helps, **the other factors in the L_O Equation are known**. V_OUT = 7.4V, V_IN =50V, F_SW (Swithcing frequency) = 100kHz

Also, what do they mean by *"choose a buck inductance such that the inductor ripple current, ΔI_L, is between 30% to 50% of the maximum DC output current at nominal input voltage"*?

Comment: Your current ripple is a trade off between inductor size and transistor+capacitor cost/size. With hypothetical zero ESR and ESL capacitor, you can choose as high current ripple as you want. 30-50 % gives realistic trade-offs. Have you tried to simulate your circuit with realistic output capacitor and tried to vary the inductance to build Your understanding?

Comment: @winny I haven't tried that. But shouldn't that formula give an estimated inductance value, and from there on just pick an inductor with a higher maximum dc current than what we need (and high saturation current)? This is my first SMD board attempt and I'm not sure how to find any of the I_L(peak), I_OUT, and ∆I_L to find the other, and then integrate it into the equation 15. I suppose we could find I_L(peak) and I_OUT?

Comment: Note that higher current ripple in the inductor also increases AC and core losses in the inductor which can affect efficiency.  It's all a tradeoff.

Comment: The formula is already given, but you need to learn and understand the tradeoff or you’ll end up with cooked capacitors or huge chokes. I_OUT you must know since it’s a design parameter.

Comment: @winny I understood the formula, but what are the tradeoffs I need to know? I_OUT is known, 35A. Higher ripple current = lower efficiency? By ripple current you mean ΔI_L, right? And if so, how can we reduce it?

Also, I figured out the inductance to be 6 micro Henry in the answer below

Comment: Not necessarily, but high current peaks will cause losses in capacitor ESR, coil DCR and MOSFET Rdson. To decrease it, you need higher inductance. At 35 A, you’re probably better off with a two phase buck. Yes, ΔI_L is the current ripple.

Comment: @winny The IC is also capable of working as a **2-phase buck regulator**, check [page 51 in the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5143a-q1.pdf?ts=1690023068948&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM5143A-Q1). So we should go with reference design 3 (2 phase) instead of the single phase reference design 1 (page 40 in datasheet)? 2 phase designs can handle more current and have lower ripple voltage?

Comment: Definitely. Ask me how I know.

Comment: @winny How do you know...? Also, **the equation for calculating the Inductance stays the same for both 1 phase and 2 phase applications, right?** Or do we have to slice it in 2 once we obtain it since they're holding half the current they used to? From what I see the double phase is simply a 1-phase, but with **2 separate identical circuits outputs (V_OUT) merged together**. They both have the same components, are symmetric, and have their outputs connected together (page 51)

Comment: Ideally half the current. I didn’t plow though the datasheet, hopefully there is a good servo mechanism to keep the currents equal. Switching noise, heat concentration and difficult layout due to the very large single inductor. There is a reason why PC motherboards run 8 phases for 120 A of current.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147404/discussion-between-mito-and-winny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ΔI<sub>L</sub> "is between 30 to 50%" of I<sub>OUT</sub>.

I<sub>OUT</sub> is the steady-state output current.

I<sub>L(pk)</sub> is the peak, or half the delta above the average.

Δ is a symbol used to denote an overall change in a parameter.  Inductor current cycles up and down around the steady-state output (that's how it works, it's being switched).  ΔI<sub>L</sub> is the peak-to-peak range of that current.  The amounts can all be solved from the inductor equation \$V = L \dfrac{dI}{dt}\$, taking dees as deltas during each phase of the switching waveform (square-wave voltage causes triangle-wave current).

Note that choosing a lower ripple fraction also degrades current limiting ability (i.e., PWM depends on V<sub>OUT</sub> as well as peak current), which is probably why they include a separate current-limiting function (which will  however be susceptible to chaotic behavior because it's simply a no-slope peak current threshold).  Presumably that limit will only be used transiently, so the instability doesn't have a big impact on power dissipation or emissions.

Permissible ripple fraction depends upon slope compensation factor, see §9.3.13.

Comment: So **that** was it! If ΔIL is I_OUT * 30% (or anything in 30-50 range), then the value of IL(pk) is known too! In our case, I_OUT will be 35A, Input voltage 50, output 7.4, so ΔIL= 35*30/100 = 10.5! Knowing this, we can calculate L_O using equation (15) and it will be: **7.4/(10.5*100*10^3)*(50-7.4/50) = 6 micro Henry Inductor**! Is this right? Did I get it?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: could you clarify me if **high ripple current** is bad? If yes, then how can it be lowered. And also, when picking an inductor I should get one with a saturation current higher than that of the IL(pk), right? From what I understood, saturation is the point where inductance lowers, which is **not** good as far as I know?

Comment: "Bad" in what sense? Yes, saturation should generally be above Ipk.

Comment: Bad in the sense it will affect the circuit the buck converter powers. Like burn an IC or capacitor. From what I understand ripple current is a variation of the current in a sine wave-style, which (maybe) is not good?

Comment: That's a separate question, but consider topics such as: loop inductance, core loss, dielectric loss / loss tangent, efficiency calculations, etc.

Comment: Ok, do you have any link you think would be useful in learning more about those? I really want to be on the safe side with this PCB. As a last question, what does the maximum DC resistance mean? What is its purpose?

Comment: Of what? Inductor? The maximum DC resistance it has. Maximum with respect to manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: Ok, when picking an inductor, does it matter its maximum DC resistance? Should I aim for ones that are as low as possible, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Mito Ripple current in this application is a triangle wave, not a sine wave.

Comment: @Mito Yes, DC resistance matters a lot. Make it as low as you can; it directly determines much of the efficiency, and if it's too high the converter won't work at all.